# Is there a way to specify an association_foreign_key for a belongs_to relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, belongs-to

I have a model that uses a `belongs_to` relation. I want to be able to specify both the `foreign_key` and `association_foreign_key` values. However, I can only specify the `foreign_key` value for a `belongs_to` relation (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference) Is there a way to solve this problem?

Here is my example:

I have a Client model. Its `location_id` key has to belong to the Region model, where ids are referred to by `place_id`. What I'd like to do is:

```
class ClientId < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region, foreign_key: 'location_id', association_foreign_key: 'place_id'
```

However, I cannot specify the `association_foreign_key` here...

Comment: You haven’t explained this that clearly. Are you saying that the primary key of a `Region` is `place_id`? You don’t need `association_foreign_key` in this case because it’s not a `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The association doesn't need to be declared both ways in the same model. You have to declare:
has_one/many in the other related model.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region, foreign_key: 'location_id'

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients, foreign_key: 'place_id'
```

Comment: ok thanks! Just to make sure: does has_many make sense if there is 0 relation? For instance here a region can have 0 client. That's why I was reluctant to specify this relation in the `Region` model

Comment: Your Region.clients will return and empty record if called. But you might need to send emails to some customers in a region, or filter the suggestions algorithm. Who knows...

Comment: according to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference (4.1.2.6) and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference (4.3.2.9) the foreign_key refers to the key in the same table for the has_many and in the other table for the belongs_to. So here both should be equals to `'location_id'` right?

Comment: Let's suppose you have a Customer with region_id 1.
And you you have a Region with Id: 1

When declaring has_many :customers and calling: Region.find(1).customers rails will search in the Customers the whole array of customers with region_id: 1.

And when declaron a belongs_to: region. When doing Customers.first.region rails will look for the region_id: 1 and return a single object.

The foreign key can be named out of the convention. Region_name: Region_continent. And rails will go to the table Regions and look in that field for this region.